# echo php array in html table loop

Tags: php, html, loops

Please run the html snippet https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YeoZQr, i want to make like this with array and foreach, I spend few hours but didn't successed, please any help will be appreciated.

my php code:

```
<?
$do['a']['ask'] = 'Do you agree with me';
$do['a']['text'][] = 'Completely Agree';
$do['a']['text'][] = 'Agree';
$do['a']['text'][] = 'Neutral';
$do['a']['text'][] = 'Disagree';
$do['a']['text'][] = 'Completely Disagree';

$do['b']['ask'] = 'All people are differents';
$do['b']['text'][] = 'Completely Agree';
$do['b']['text'][] = 'Agree';
$do['b']['text'][] = 'Neutral';
$do['b']['text'][] = 'Disagree';
$do['b']['text'][] = 'Completely Disagree';

foreach($do as $key => $value)
{
    $text= $do[$key]['text'];
    foreach($text as $ask_key => $ask_value)
    {
        echo "<table>
        <tr>
            <td style=\"width:50%;\"></td>
            <td>".$ask_value."</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>".$do[1]['ask']."</td>
            <td><input type=\"radio\" name=".$key." value=".$ask_value." /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>";
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: In the link, the possible answers are the same for each question. Your data structure repeats them, though they are the same in both copies. If they're going to be the same, you should save only a single copy of the answers, separate from the list of questions; if they're going to vary from question to question, then your link isn't useful as a formatting example to follow.

Comment: yes, but each question has it own answer, can you do an example or fix my code for me please?

Comment: I'm still not clear on whether the list of *possible* answers is always going to be the same. Obviously, the user might choose a different answer for a than for b, but could a and b ever have a different set of acceptable responses?

Comment: yes, user might choose different radio answer for a and b

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to print the headers first (at least what I think at the moment). Then print the inputs on the next batch.

```
echo '<table cellpadding=10>';
// print headers
echo '<tr><td></td>'; // empty cell
foreach ($do['a']['text'] as $text) {
    echo "<th>{$text}</th>";
}

// print rows
foreach ($do as $key => $value) {
    $ask = $value['ask']; // label for the row
    $radio_value = $value['text']; // values for radio button for each row
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$ask}</td>";
    foreach ($radio_value as $radio) { // loop the values and create a list of radio buttons
        echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"input[{$key}]\" value=\"{$radio}\" /></td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Just use the key for each row (the `a` and `b`) for the name attribute so that they could be grouped, and therefore make sense in a form context.

If you control the array also, yes you could simplify it by separating both the questions and the choices (if the choices are constant).

```
$questions = ['a' => 'Do you agree with me', 'b' => 'All people are differents'];
$choices = ['Completely Agree', 'Agree', 'Neutral', 'Disagree', 'Completely Disagree'];

echo '<table cellpadding=10>';
// print headers
echo '<tr><td></td>'; // empty cell
foreach ($choices as $text) {
    echo "<th>{$text}</th>";
}
// print rows
foreach ($questions as $key => $question) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>{$question}</td>";
    foreach ($choices as $radio) { // loop the values and create a list of radio buttons
        echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=\"input[{$key}]\" value=\"{$radio}\" /></td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

The same concept is applied, print the headers then the questions. Then accessing values is also the same as you do in forms. Use the proper `<form>` tag with the appropriate `method = POST / GET` (which ever you prefer) and just access them accordingly:

```
$input = $_GET['input'];
// or
$input = $_POST['input'];
foreach ($input as $question_key => $selected_choice) {
    // $question_key contains a or b
    // $selected_choice contains the selected radio
    // do what you have to do
}
```

<sup>Just ignore the form bit part if this is already obvious to you.</sup>

Comment: ok thank you for your answer, I will test and let you know. Is there any way to avoid repeating this part of code "Completely Agree", "Agree", "Neutral"..etc because it's the same, only questions is changed? any way to minimize code please?

Comment: @JohnJack this answer is only based on the array above, of course it can be simplified if the text choices are always the same, i'm under the impression that the array above cannot be modified, i'll draft another answer if thats the case

Comment: yes, you are right. I will be grateful if you can help me to do it without repeating the "Completely Agree", "Agree", "Neutral".. test choose are always the same but results and user can select different answer for each question. thank you very much

Comment: the problem in your updated code is you make array different array, i want to keep it like that: $do['a']['ask'] = 'Do you agree with me'; any idea what to change?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, it can be perfect but it can resolve this issue

```
<?php
$do['a']['ask'] = 'Do you agree with me';
$do['a']['text'][] = 'Completely Agree';
$do['a']['text'][] = 'Agree';
$do['a']['text'][] = 'Neutral';
$do['a']['text'][] = 'Disagree';
$do['a']['text'][] = 'Completely Disagree';

$do['b']['ask'] = 'All people are differents';
$do['b']['text'][] = 'Completely Agree';
$do['b']['text'][] = 'Agree';
$do['b']['text'][] = 'Neutral';
$do['b']['text'][] = 'Disagree';
$do['b']['text'][] = 'Completely Disagree';
$html = '<table>';
$header = '';
$i = 0;
foreach ($do as $key => $value) {
    if (!$i++) {// onetime
        if (!$header) {//one time
            $header .= '<tr><td styl="width:50%;"></td>';
            foreach ($do[$key]['text'] as $texthead) {
                $header .= "<td>$texthead</td>";
            }
            $header .= '</tr>';
        }
        $html .= $header;
    }
    $html.='<tr>';
    foreach ($value as $k => $val) {
        if($k=='ask'){
            $html.="<td>$val</td>";
        }else{
            foreach ($val as $v){
                $html.="<td><input type='radio' name='$key' value='$v' /></td>";
            }

        }
    }
    $html.='</tr>';
}
$html .= '</table>';
echo $html;?>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will test and tell you. Is there any way to avoid repeating this part of code "Completely Agree", "Agree", "Neutral"..etc because it's the same, only questions is changed? any way to minimize code please?

Comment: Cyril Lemaire already simplified in this way, using a similar structure to your own, I rewrote things a bit, but have as well. Just a heads up... @Bai Nguyen, not that you need it, but if you want to look to either of our answers in reworking yours, it's done for you. (I know I had to test twice to make sure I got the structure right, printed headers twice the first time)

Comment: Ok, i will not update my answer again. i only use some php function replace for foreach only (i think) but had better we need change array

Answer (score 0):

What I think is the simplest solution is to rewrite your arrays, so you aren't storing the same data multiple times.

```
$questions = ['a'=>'Do you agree with me','b'=>'All people are differents'];
$options = ['Completely Agree','Agree','Neutral','Disagree','Completely Disagree'];
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>";
foreach($options as $option){
  echo "<td>".$option."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
foreach($questions as $id => $question){
  echo "<tr><td>".$question."</td>";
  foreach($options as $option){
        echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" name=".$id." value=".$option." /></td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

This assumes your answer options will never change.

Answer (score 0):

To make it look like your attempt you could do something like that

```
<?php
$radio = [
    'questions' => [],
    'choices' => []
];

$radio['questions']['a'] = 'Do you agree with me';
$radio['questions']['b'] = 'All people are differents';

$radio['choices'][] = 'Completely Agree';
$radio['choices'][] = 'Agree';
$radio['choices'][] = 'Neutral';
$radio['choices'][] = 'Disagree';
$radio['choices'][] = 'Completely Disagree';

echo "<table><tr><td style=\"width:50%;\"></td>";

foreach($radio['choices'] as $choice)
{
    echo "<td>$choice</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";

foreach($radio['questions'] as $id => $question)
{
    echo "<tr><td>$choice</td>";
    foreach($radio['choices'] as $choice)
    {
        echo "<td><input type="radio" name='$id' value='$choice'/></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Edit: I changed the `foreach($question)` because I simply copied your example yesterday night and didn't set the `value` tag.

So, I think you noticed but I took the liberty to rename your variable (`do` => `radio`, `ask` => `questions`, `text` => `choices`). The main point to avoid repeating data is to make clear which variable "directly depends" on which other one.

To create your whole radio you will need everything (That's logic since this code only creates said radio), so I made (just like you) the `$radio` table that contains all choices and questions.
Then, we have the questions. To create each of them you need an access to their text, their id, and the whole set of `choices`. But since the `choices` are the same for every question, they don't need to "possess" the choices. What "depends" on the question (what **might change** for each question) are just it's id and text. So that's what I stored in every `$radio['questions']`, an associative array of `$id`=> `$question_text` (once again just like you)
So just as stated earlier if the `choices` don't depend directly on one question then they're the `radio` set of choices. So they belong directly to `radio`.

Now to create the radio table we can simply iterate over the choices to create the first row (labels), and for each question text and id we create a new row with the question text and for each choice a radio box with the corresponding id.

This method of an *array like and object* is pretty cool for it's wrapping of data and concision if you want to create a `createRadio($radio)` function for example. But it gets a little boring if you may want to only print some of the questions of a radio (you need to create a whole new `$radio`).

Another option is to "dissolve" the concept of `$radio` in two arrays `$questions`and `$choices`, that's what [@TCooper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122015/echo-php-array-in-html-table-loop#answer-49122242) did in his answer. It makes you lose the *data centralisation* (in this case that difference is very slim). The advantages on the other hand is that you can more freely modify your questions and choices (to limit the number of questions or restrict the set of choices, you only need to change the corresponding table), and one doesn't need to know how you conceived the `$radio` array to call a `createRadio($questions, $choices)` function.

Comment: ok thank you and no problem, hope you can explain tomorrow :)

Comment: Edited, let me know if I made some mistake / was too wide of the mark.